# Convergence of power series under a given condition

Tags: convergence-divergence, power-series, proof-explanation

The question i am trying to figure out is:

> If the series $\sum_{1}^\infty |a_n-a_{n-1}|$ is convergent, then
>   where should the power series $\sum_{0}^\infty a_n{x^n} $ converge?

The answer given simply says it would converge on SOME set that contains the open interval (-1,1). I didn't get the concept/ theory that works here. Any helpful reference or supporting proof would be appreciated.

Comment: Thank you foe pointing out. Edited. I meant the series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\sum_{n=1}^\infty|a_n-a_{n-1}|$ converges, so does $\sum_{n=1}^\infty(a_n-a_{n-1})$. This implies that
$$
a_n=a_0+\sum_{k=1}^n(a_k-a_{k-1})
$$
converges, and in particular, it is bounded. From this, it follows easily that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$ converges absolutely if $x<1$.

Comment: Sir this surely implies that the power series converges in (-1,1), but what baffled me here is the claim that it converges in ANY set containing (-1,1). Could you please explain sir?

Comment: That is not correct. Consider $a_n=n$.

Comment: Sir doesn't $a_n=n$  diverge? Rather if we take $1\over n^2$ , then the power series converges absolutely in [-1,1] thereby eliminating the compulsion of being restricted to (-1,1) for convergence.

Comment: You are right. It should have been $a_n=1$.